# bibtex style -> incorrect ouput!

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to use the acs-chem style with bibtex backend. There is something going wrong somewhere on two levels.

1. The month is being included when only the year should be
2. Papers with 10 authors (or more are being shortened with et. al.

Neither of these things (correct me if I'm wrong) should be happening.
The .tex is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,BCOR13mm,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}

This reference should not have a month \cite{someguy1},
This one has et al. for some reason!\cite{someguy2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the MWE.bib looks like this:

```
@article{someguy1,
abstract = {},
author = {1, 1firstname and 2, 2firstname R and 3, 3firstname and 4, 4firstname and 5, 5firstname W and 6, 6firstname and 7, 7firstname E and 8, 8firstname and 9, 9firstname R},
journal = {journal1},
month = nov,
number = {1},
pages = {1-10000},
pmid = {},
publisher = {},
title = {{title1}},
volume = {1},
year = {1066}
}


@article{someguy2,
abstract = {},
author = {1, 1firstname and 2, 2firstname R and 3, 3firstname and 4, 4firstname and 5, 5firstname W and 6, 6firstname and 7, 7firstname E and 8, 8firstname and 9, 9firstname R and 10, 10firstname and 11, 11firstname and 12, 12firstname and 13, 13firstname and 14, 14firstname a and 15, 15firstname and 16, 16firstname and 17, 17firstname},
journal = {journal2},
month = aug,
number = {2},
pages = {2-20000},
pmid = {},
publisher = {},
title = {{title2}},
volume = {2},
year = {2066}
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you not using `{}` for month?

Comment: it appears that is how my reference manager makes the .bib file (Mendeley)

Comment: Why do you think they should not happen?

Comment: @Urhaving seen an ACS journal for one... also [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACS_style)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 
Having seen an ACS journal, also [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACS_style) and the [ACS style guide](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch014)

Comment: If you think that this is wrong and the correct output according to ACS guidelines has to be otherwise, you might want to notify the author of this, so he can incorporate a fix. Drop by the [`biblatex-chem` bug tracker over at github](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/issues).

Comment: adding the braces to the month does solve the month issue so I guess that is a problem for Mendeley to sort out when it creates the .bib file. 
As for the number of authors I think that because the ACS style is generalised for many journals with varying specific requirements the maxbibnames fix is probably the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the maxbibnames value and suppress the month field for articles like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,BCOR13mm,twoside,openright,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{month}}{}}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\begin{document}

This reference should not have a month \cite{someguy1},
This one has et al. for some reason!\cite{someguy2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```